# Cordova window.print not working for the page loaded via inappbrowser

Tags: javascript, cordova, printing, cordova-plugins

I've loaded the webpage in the cordova app as below:

```
window.open('https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/', '', '');
```

There is a page `https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/data.html` on which a print button is present (which will print the content by using `window.print`).
**Please note that button is present on the webpage loaded via window.open**

Below is the code to print the content:

```
var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
WinPrint.document.write(html);
WinPrint.document.close();
WinPrint.focus();
WinPrint.print();
WinPrint.close();
```

But, when I'm trying to print the part of page, it just opens a new window. Print window does not show up. Can anyone help me to sort this out?

Comment: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer

Comment: @johnborges I've tried this plugin, but it won't work. As I said, print button is on the webpage which is loaded in the inappbrowser. And I think this plugin will work only if the button is present in the app itself. In that case, I can load the webpage in the new window and print it. But, I want to print the page via button on the page in an inappbrowser.

Comment: @ghanashyam Did you solve it?

Comment: I am also facing similar issue, did you find the solution?